# SQL charindex throwing Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function because of period?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got the lines below in the where clause of my query, but I keep getting this error:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

    SUBSTRING(
        [email], 
        1, 
        CHARINDEX('@',[email])-1
    ) =
    SUBSTRING(
        [email], 
        CHARINDEX('@',[email])+1,
        CHARINDEX('.', [email])
    )
```

The error is originating from `CHARINDEX('.', [email])`

If I change the period to a letter, I don't get the error.  Every record has a period in it, and even if one didn't, the charindex function would return 0, which wouldn't cause this error to throw.  I must be missing something simple. Please help!

EDIT.

I tried throwing it inside an isnull,  `isnull(CHARINDEX('.', [email]), 1)` just in case it was returning null for some reason, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 26):

The error is originating from

```
CHARINDEX('@',[email])-1
```

If there is no @ symbol in the data, charindex returns 0.  You subtract one from that to get -1, which is invalid in the substring function.

Try this instead.

```
CHARINDEX('@',[email] + '@')-1
```

This forces there to be a match, making sure CharIndex will always return a value >= 1, which will cause your substring function to succeed.

Comment: +1 This is the only thing that makes since... but the OP said "If I change the period to a letter, I don't get the error."

Comment: I understand, but that cannot be true.  The 2nd parameter can be a negative number (although I admit that is weird).  The 3rd parameter must be a "positive integer".  This includes 0.  The only possible way to get an invalid length parameter is to have the 3rd parameter be negative (less than 0).  Charindex cannot return a negative number, so the problem cannot be with the 2nd substring function, and MUST be the 3rd parameter of the first substring function.

Comment: Thanks!  The table i'm running it on is extremely large, so when I ran the query with a letter in place of the period, results started populating for a couple minutes before it hit one without the @ symbol and threw the error (sorry, not catching this was due to my impatience).  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is your only problem.  I am guessing that you are trying to look at the first part of an e-mail address and compare it with the first part of the domain.  For example if the e-mail address is "name@company.com" then you are looking for "name" and "company".  Substring does not take 2 positions, it takes a position and a length.  Therefore to get "company" you would need to do this:

```
SUBSTRING(
    [email],
    CHARINDEX('@', [email]) + 1,
    CHARINDEX('.', [email]) - CHARINDEX('@', [email]) - 1
)
```

The +1 and -1 are to account for the fact that CHARINDEX would give you the position of the "@" so it would include the "@" in the result.

Unfortunately this won't always work because if you have an address like "first.last@company.com" then the position of the first "." will be less than the position of the "@" resulting in a negative number.

Therefore you will need to do this:

```
SUBSTRING(
    [email],
    CHARINDEX('@', [email]) + 1,
    CHARINDEX('.', [email], CHARINDEX('@', [email])) - CHARINDEX('@', [email]) - 1
)
```

This would make sure you are looking for the first "." after the "@".  However, this still doesn't work if  you don't have a "@" but you do have a "." (such as "invalidemail.companay.com").  Therefor you could do the solution above to add a '@' to the end, but a better way would be like this:

```
SUBSTRING(
    [email],
    CHARINDEX('@', [email]) + 1,
    CASE WHEN 
        CHARINDEX('.', [email], CHARINDEX('@', [email])) - CHARINDEX('@', [email]) - 1 < 0 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE 
        CHARINDEX('.', [email], CHARINDEX('@', [email])) - CHARINDEX('@', [email]) - 1
    END
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a ' ' at the end of the line with error like

```
SUBSTRING(
    [email], 
    1, 
    CHARINDEX('@',[email]+' ')-1
) =
SUBSTRING(
    [email], 
    CHARINDEX('@',[email])+1,
    CHARINDEX('.', [email])
)
```