# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function error

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-length

I have the following code but I am getting the error,

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Code:

```
SELECT        
    Main.HostName, LEFT(Main.Users, Len(Main.Users) - 1) AS [Users]
FROM            
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         ST2.HostName,
         (SELECT ST1.UserName + ', ' AS [text()]
          FROM dbo.USERS ST1
          WHERE ST1.HostName = ST2.HostName
          ORDER BY ST1.HostName FOR XML PATH('')) [Users]
     FROM           
         dbo.USERS ST2) [Main]
```

I am trying to left most user in each row.

Comment: Any chance you have a Users with 0 character?

Comment: Check Main.Users column, it could be null or ''.

Comment: This is easily found by using google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL charindex throwing Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function because of period?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946833/sql-charindex-throwing-invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-left-or-substring)

Comment: Yes I added + ', ' after the Len(Main.Users) and that ran my query but each cell now ends in ','. Do you know know to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have `Main.Users` with an empty string (len = 0)